# Shouldn't CallBack on Room delete all database in this code?

Tags: android-studio, android-room

I have just followed this guide: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#12

(not only page 12 but all from 1 to 17).

On that link it shows the following code:

```
private static RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);

        // If you want to keep data through app restarts,
        // comment out the following block
        databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {
            // Populate the database in the background.
            // If you want to start with more words, just add them.
            WordDao dao = INSTANCE.wordDao();
            dao.deleteAll();

            Word word = new Word("Hello");
            dao.insert(word);
            word = new Word("World");
            dao.insert(word);
        });
    }
};
```

Here's link to the RoomDatabse class:
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordRoomDatabase.java

Since inside the callback there's dao.deletaAll() function which deletes all SQL data. In the code it says "If you want to keep data through app restarts, comment out the following block" above the code as comment.

So when I close and restart the app the words I added should be removed and I should only see "Hello" and "World". But the words I added still are there when I close and I restart the app. Is there something I misunderstood about how the app works?

Why the data keeps through app restarts despite I haven't commented out the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onCreate** is only called once for the lifetime of the database. That is it is only called when the database doesn't exist and needs to be created.

If you uninstalled the App and then ran the App then **onCreate** would be called as the database would then be deleted.

- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback#onCreate(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase)

Perhaps you want to override the **onOpen** method rather than the **onCreate** method.

- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback#onOpen(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase)